# Encrypted Word File gives Error while opening in Office 365 site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, word, password

I have created a Word file with a password and uploaded to my Office 365 SharePoint site. When I try to open the uploaded Word file in Word Online it gives an Error message. The file is opening after downloaded to my desktop and asks for password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password protected documents cannot be opened within Office Online. You must use the Office client application (Word, Excel, etc.) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. Is any other way kindly suggest me.

Comment: No, Office Online apps are lightweight and don't give the same full functionality of the client.